# Is "...that he doesn't even know where is" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

I was recently invited to a party by a Facebook friend. I asked him where the party was happening, and he said he couldn't remember the address. While texting someone else about the experience, I wrote:

> My friend just invited me to a party *that he doesn't even know where is.*

The italicized phrase is intended to be synonymous with "that he doesn't even know the location of", but I thought that alternative might sound stilted and overly formal. Would this phrase be grammatically correct?

Comment: Phrased this way, it's unidomatic. A less formal way to phrase it, that a naive speaker might actually employ, and a pedant disdain, would be "*that even he doesn't know where **it** is*".

Comment: @DanBron A naïve speaker? ;-) More seriously, though, I find the construction in the question fairly natural and idiomatic, though highly colloquial, and the one in Dan’s example jarring and unnatural (as well as highly colloquial). I know lots of people say it and thus find it idiomatic, but it has always jarred as much to me as “a party that he doesn't even know the location of it” or the increasingly popular ‘empty’ use of _which_, as in “He invited us to a vernissage, which I don't even think he knows what that is”.

Comment: More natural than both, of course, is “He invited me to this party, but he doesn't even know where it is”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That may be better grammatically, but it likely doesn't fit with the stream of consciousness of the speaker. After saying _party_, you tend to want to use a phrase that's descriptive of it, rather than referring back to the subject of the sentence. I don't think there's any relative clause that's grammatical but not overly wordy, and grammar tends to lose that battle.

Comment: This seems clear and direct: "My friend just invited me to a party *but* he doesn't even know where the party is located." (or "...happening.")  What seems to matter most is the contrast between the friend issuing the invitation, which implies some association with the hosts of the party, and the friend not knowing the location, which implies no association with the party hosts.  Using "but" instead of "that" shifts attention to this contrast.